# Почему методы копируются по значению?! Это же функции

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';
var a = {
    m() {console.log('hello')}
};
var b = a.m;
a.m = null;
b();
```

Comment: В комментариях нельзя пример привести, поэтому отправил в ответ. И даже если весь объект прихлопнуть, ссылка останется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они копируются по ссылке и если вы скопировали ссылку на метод а `var b = a.m;`, то занулив ссылку у `a.m`, сам метод никуда не делся и у вас осталась ссылка на него в `b`.

```js
'use strict';
var a = {
    m() {console.log('hello')}
};
var b = a.m;

//меняем переменную у a.m, по значению не должен изменить b
a.m.test = "10"; 
//один и тот же объект, следовательно копирование было не по значению
console.log(b.test);
```

Comment: А чё такое test? 

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff функции тоже являются объектами, только типа Function, поэтому я вполне могу запихнуть в неё переменную. `function a() { ... }; a.test = 20;` или даже `a["test"] = 20` и работать как с объектом.

Comment: Попробуйте без test

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff попробовать что? Ну по крайней мере я не понимаю, что вы хотите сказать тем, что скопировали ссылку из одной переменной в другую и считаете это копированием по значению. Ну могу картинками еще пояснить, если надо, мне не сложно.

Comment: А кто мне минусы ставит???

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff, кому-то видимо не понравился ваш вопрос, либо его посчитали слишком легким, либо не полезным для остальных, либо что-то еще. Не обращайте на них внимания, это давняя проблема этого сайта и до сих пор никто не знает, что с этим делать. От меня - уравнял))

Answer (score 0):

По сути Объект это коробка, в которую можно всё что угодно класть и брать

```js
let a = {
    m:()=>{console.log('hello');}
};
// m = Семечко
// a = Яблоко (с Семечкой)

const b = a.m; // к Б присваиваешь Семечку
a = null; // Яблоко с Семечкой удаляешь
b(); // Семечка
```

`'use strict';` и `var` - означают старые стандарты